# Java Stream of objects from binary file

Tags: java, file, stream, nio

I'm trying to read a file that contains a list of objects that there is easy to parse them by reading some bytes step to step. 
But in this case I need to have a stream of objects.
By searching all I got was `Stream<String> Files.lines` that is only suitable for text files not binary ones.

So how I can generate stream of objects from binary file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two main options:

1. Implement a [`Spliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html), then create a stream from it by calling [`StreamSupport.stream(Spliterator<T> spliterator, boolean parallel)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#stream-java.util.Spliterator-boolean-)
2. Implement a [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html), then create a stream from it by calling [`Stream.generate(Supplier<T> s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-)

#2 is the easiest:

```
try (BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
    Stream.generate(() -> readNext(in))
          .forEach(obj -> ...); // or whatever your stream needs to do
}
```

```
static MyObject readNext(BufferedReader in) {
    // code here
}
```

Comment: What is the advantages of first option over second one?

Comment: @mojtab23 `Spliterator` optionally supports parallel streaming. Since you can't parallel read a file stream, the `generate()` approach is easier, here.